# How to change Wordpress Logo URL in Genesis Block Theme

Tags: wordpress, genesis

So, there is a random function called genesis_block_theme_title_logo() that is supposed to display the logo and have the url for the logo when clicked on, but I can't seem too ion the function.

I need to just change the url the logo is pointing to. I cloned this website from another one, so it's still pointing to a previous one.

Comment: You should have option to change logo under Theme Settings page in your backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it under `inc/template-tags.php`.